# What is wrong with my recursion to create permutations of a string?

Tags: java, string, recursion, permutation

It is printing out a few permutations but the rest are null and I'm not sure why. I need to but all the permutations into String[] and I can't import any other package except for util.Arrays. Please help!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DIE
{

    public static String[] printPermutations(String s)
    {
        int l = s.length();
        int f = factorial(l);
        int count = 0;
        String[] array = new String[f];
        permute("", s, array, 0);
        Arrays.sort(array);
        return array;
    }

    private static String[] permute(String x, String s, String [] array, int count)
    {
        int l = s.length(); 
        if (l == 0)
        {
            array[count] = (x + s);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            permute(x + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + 
                    s.substring(i +1, s.length()), array, count);
            count++;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int factorial(int l)
    {
        if (l == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int result = l * factorial(l - 1);
            return result;
        }
    }

    /*
    Do not edit anything below this comment.
    */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] permutations = printPermutations(args[0]);
        for(String p : permutations)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of inputs are you giving? Post some examples, because I don't think this code is working properly for inputs like "Fable", "Cradle" etc

Comment: I've just been trying simple strings like abc abcd

Comment: In the main program, you don't need that for loop to print the array. Just remove the entire for loop and use :System.out.println(permutations);

Comment: yes that what I thought, but I'm not allowed to change main and we have to return the substrings in a String[], unless i can return it in another form without changing main

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Your count variable is wrong. Within the outermost call to `permute("", "abc", ...)` it is incremented only by one, even though the call to the next level `permute("a", "bc", ...)` creates two permutations!

There are two possible solutions:

- Instead of a `String[]` to collect your result use a `List<String>`. Then you don't need to manually count the number of permutations.
- let `permute` return the new count (instead of the result array, that one is never used anyway)

---

For `permute` to return the new count the method would look like this:

```
private static int permute(String x, String s, String [] array, int count)
{
    int l = s.length(); 
    if (l == 0)
    {
        array[count++] = x;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        count = permute(x + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + 
                s.substring(i +1, s.length()), array, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Using a `List<String>` would need some more changes, but the `permute` function would be smaller:

```
public static List<String> printPermutations(String s)
{
    int l = s.length();
    int f = factorial(l);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(f);
    permute("", s, result);
    Collections.sort(result);
    return result;
}

private static void permute(String x, String s, List<String> result)
{
    int l = s.length(); 
    if (l == 0)
    {
        result.add(x);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        permute(x + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + 
                s.substring(i +1, s.length()), result);
    }
}
```

And some small changes in the main method due to the changed result of `printPermutations` (IMHO a very bad named method: it prints out nothing, it creates the permutations together with a helper method)

Comment: sorry could you explain more what you mean by let permute return the new count that what i was trying to do by including it in the formal parameters